# Convert Hex string to normal String in C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have got this code from somewhere to convert hex string to normal string.
But I cannot understand this. Can anybody explain this please ?
In this string, The first line takes each two characters from the string and convert it to byte.
But, I dont understand why they are assigning array to only half length of byte array ?

Sometimes it gets error too, i.e if Inputstring length is 350, byte length would be 175, and char length is 87.5, and char array is assigned to 87 only, thats not enough to hold all the characters in byte array.

```
public static string HextoString(string InputText)
{

    byte[] bb = Enumerable.Range(0, InputText.Length)
                 .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                 .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(InputText.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                 .ToArray();
   //return Convert.ToBase64String(bb);
    char[] chars = new char[bb.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bb, 0, chars, 0, bb.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `.Where(x => x % 2 == 0)` filters the input string to only those values, that have even indexes, so the output will have half the length of the original.